Custom Curve in Flutter
I am developing an App using flutter and came across a custom curve like structure and I have no Idea how to create one. I am sharing a screenshot for the same.

I did some research and found that it might be possible with clip path widget but again I have no clue how will that work. I would also appreciate if someone also explained how to solve this.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

A clean way to do this is using a ShapeBorder, so you can use it on any container. Similar to the ClipPath widget, you can define a path to use. The ShapeBorder gets you the path from a bounding Rect of this Container. In the code below, I draw the top arc above this rect, so the top border aligns (and you can put other Widgets right above this container too).
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WavyBorder extends ShapeBorder {
  const WavyBorder({this.radius = 32});

  final double radius;

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.zero;

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return Path()
      // The top curve is above this container's Rect, keep this in mind with your other Widgets
      ..moveTo(rect.topLeft.dx, rect.topLeft.dy - radius)
      // The 90 degree arc at the top
      ..relativeArcToPoint(
        Offset(radius, radius),
        radius: Radius.circular(radius),
        clockwise: false,
      )
      // The horizontal line
      ..lineTo(rect.topRight.dx - radius, rect.topRight.dy)
      // The 90 degree arc at the bottom
      ..relativeArcToPoint(
        Offset(radius, radius),
        radius: Radius.circular(radius),
      )
      // Then just visit the bottom corners normally
      ..lineTo(rect.bottomRight.dx, rect.bottomRight.dy)
      ..lineTo(rect.bottomLeft.dx, rect.bottomLeft.dy)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}

Then, wherever you want to use it, you can add it in the ShapeDecoration of your Container:
Container(
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
    shape: WavyBorder(radius: 32),
    ...
  ),
  child: ...,
),

Which looks like this:

Complete code for usage (main.dart):
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'wavy_container.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: HomeScreen(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.text = 'Hallo';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Flex(
        direction: Axis.vertical,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'This text fits neatly above the container. Watch out with the left margin right above it though!',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                shape: const WavyBorder(radius: 32),
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Look at that pretty wavy border above here!',
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .headlineLarge
                    ?.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Maybe this code is not the best way but it was easiest to make UI like this
Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
          appBar: CustomAppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[500],
            title: '',
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey[500],
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(56),
                  ),
                ),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 200,
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.grey[500],
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(70),
                    ),
                  ),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 200,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),


